# Android OpenGL ES display image fullscreen with aspect ratio

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to display an image fullscreen in my OpenGL app without losing its aspect ratio. I know that I can draw an image as a texture onto a "cube" or 2d plane. But I'm not sure if this is really the best way when I just simply want to show a 2d image.

Espcially because I want this image to be fullscreen without losing its aspect ratio. I know this is easy with an ImageView. But I need this in my OpenGL ES application.

But I have no clue how to do this. Anyone any idea?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what behavior you want. You can only display an image that completely fills a rendering surface, and maintain its aspect ratio, if the aspect ratio of the image and the aspect ratio of the rendering surface are the same. Otherwise you will either have to leave empty space, or part of the image will be cut off.

Comment: Exactly like you describe. I want to fill the surface entirely with an image. If the image can fill the entire width, but not the height, then I'd like to leave empty space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the aspect ratio of your image and the aspect ratio of your view will generally be different, there are two cases. With aspect ratio defined as width/height:

1. If the aspect ratio of the image is larger than the aspect ratio of the view, you need black bars at the top and bottom.
2. If the aspect ratio of the image is smaller than the aspect ratio of the view, you need black bars on the right and left.

Without any transformations applied, OpenGL uses a coordinate system that has a range of [-1.0, 1.0] in both the x- and y-direction. So if you draw a quad covering [-1.0, 1.0] in both directions, it will fill the entire view. Since we do not want to fill the entire range in one of the two directions, we need to scale down the y-coordinates in case 1, and the x-coordinates in case 2. The amount of scaling needed corresponds to the ratio between the two aspect ratios.

With the following values:

```
float imgAspectRatio = (float)imgWidth / (float)imgHeight;
float viewAspectRatio = (float)viewWidth / (float)viewHeight;
```

We calculate the scaling factors for x and y as:

```
float xScale = 1.0f;
float yScale = 1.0f;
if (imgAspectRatio > viewAspectRatio) {
    yScale = viewAspectRatio / imgAspectRatio;
} else {
    xScale = imgAspectRatio / viewAspectRatio;
}
```

Now all that's left is to apply these scale factors while rendering. There's multiple ways of doing that. You could use them for your input coordinates, and draw a quad that spans a range of [-xScale, xScale] in x-direction and [-yScale, yScale] in y-direction. Or you can apply the scaling in your shader, which I think is slightly more elegant. In this case, you still draw a quad with extent [-1.0, 1.0] in both directions, and use a vertex shader that could look like this:

```
#version 100
uniform vec2 ScaleFact;
attribute vec2 Position;
varying vec2 TexCoord;
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(ScaleFact * Position, 0.0, 1.0);
    TexCoord = 0.5 * Position + 0.5;
}
```

And a fragment shader that simply samples the texture:

```
#version 100
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D Tex;
varying vec2 TexCoord;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(Tex, TexCoord);
}
```

You pass in the `xScale/yScale` values we calculated above for the value of the `ScaleFact` uniform, set up the attribute location and everything else the way you normally would, and then render the [-1.0, 1.0] x [-1.0, 1.0] quad.

The advantage of doing the scaling in the shader is that you can still easily derive position and texture coordinates from a single input attribute. If you pass in the scaled positions, you would probably want a separate attribute to pass in the texture coordinates. Which is a perfectly fine thing to do as well.